# Man treibt viel Sport. Man fühlt sich fit

Tags: sentence-structure

If I want to connect these 2 sentences together with the construction: *je .... desto* ... 2 questions:

1. how would be the order of words in this sentence: would it be: "Je
   mehr man Sport treibt, desto fitter fühlt man sich" or it would be
2. "Je mehr Sport man treibt, desto fitter fühlt man sich".   can we
   use the comparative form of "fit" i.e. fitter or better to be: "Je
   mehr Sport man treibt, desto besser fühlt man sich"

Answer (score 4):

> Je mehr man Sport treibt, desto fitter fühlt man sich.
>
> Je mehr Sport man treibt, desto fitter fühlt man sich.

Both are possible. The latter one sounds more natural.

---

And yes, *fit* is a normal adjective in German, you can build comparative and superlative for it.

> fit, fitter, am fittesten

But be careful, in German it only means *gesund* and *sportlich*.

Comment: Beides stimmt für mich nicht: *Je mehr ich Sport treibe, umso müder werde ich.* ist für mich richtig.

Comment: @tofro Ich glaube der Themenersteller interessiert sich mehr für die richtige Schreibweise dieses Satzes in Deutsch und weniger für die Logik des Satzes. Außerdem fühle ich mich nachdem ich Sport nach der Arbeit gemacht habe nicht umbedingt müde sondern eher fit und entspannt. Ist schwer sowas zu pauschalisieren.

Comment: @mafin Ich glaube, dein Ironiedetektor ist kaputt.